# How to subtract a date from current time using Elasticsearch?

Tags: date, elasticsearch

I'm trying to calculate the current age of file in Elasticsearch.

My plan was to do something like current time - timestamp.

I am now using scripts to do this and managed to subtract one date field from another

```
{ "query"  : 
  { 
     "match_all" : {} 
  }, 
    "fields" : ["_source"],
    "script_fields" : 
       { "date_diff"       : 
       { "script" : "doc[\"two\"].date-doc[\"one\"].date"}
      }
}'
```

although I think it was done wrong as the answer was definitely not correct. (It worked out to thousands of days difference)

I have also tried using the Elasticsearch date-math suggestions such as "now", "time", "+1h" etc and all of these result in error

"JsonParseException[Unrecognized token 'time': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN\n at [Source: [B@220c4a0b; line: 1, column: 111]]; }]"

I'm unsure now if scripts is even the right thing to use. It seems like it should be simple to do, but I can't seem to find any examples.

Is this even possible to do? Is there a better way to do it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Can you show usecase for that? If you need to show age at UI, for example, its still better to response with creation date. If you need some analysis, filtering by creation date should do the trick.

If you are sure that you need to return "age" of document with ES query, try:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "fields": ["_source"],
  "script_fields": {
    "age": {
      "script": "(DateTime.now().getMillis() - doc['created'].value)/(24*60*60*1000)"
    }
  }
}
```

ES handles dates as unix epoch timestamps, you should cast current time to integer to reflect ms (with `DateTime.now().getMillis()`) and then subtract `doc`s value from that. This will give you age in milliseconds. Divide by any coefficient, if needed (i.e., tj get age in days)

Comment: For above query I get the below exception - "reason": {
               "type": "script_exception",
               "reason": "scripts of type [inline], operation [search] and lang [groovy] are disabled"
            }

Comment: Can't test this now, but if you're using late ES versions, groovy isn't available for such inline scripting.

Look for `painless` https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html

Or for dynamic scripting settings https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-security.html